# Installing a library from codeartifact with poetry without moving all libraries to be installed from there

Tags: python-poetry, aws-codeartifact

My situation I have a specific library in codeartifact.

I have a project (not a library) managing dependencies with poetry consuming this library.

Now I need to install this library in the project but can't find instructions which

1. Don't change the actual pypi index url for all projects in my computer
2. Being able to install the specific library from codeartifact without it being proxy for pypi for ALL libraries

Any ideas or clues on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

In order to do that you need to add a source to your `pyproject.toml` and mark it as secondary:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "my-repo"
url = "your-pypi-url"
secondary = true
```

And then point your library to this source.

With CLI:

```
poetry add my-library --source my-repo
```

Or directly in pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
…
my-library = {version = "1.0.0", source = "my-repo"}
```